# How to add 'Formula' field to the aggregate line of an Interactive Report in Oracle Apex 22.1?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm currently using an Interactive Report on APEX 22.1 that contains 3 columns; Sales Value, Profit Value, and Profit Margin. I was able to aggregate the first 2 columns as SUM using Actions -> Data -> Aggregate. But for the third column, I need it (in the aggregate line) to be a formula (Sum of Sales / Sum of Profits).

I expect the solution to be a javascript one, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: You could create a 2nd report region with the 3 aggregated values only based on a separate select.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for 'average' value of 'Profit Margin'.
totals of each columns you are getting in as aggregations any ways.
similarly Actions -> Data -> Aggregate
function-> Average column->Profit Margin